# How to create subdocuments schemas/calls for Mongoose using NextJS

Tags: mongoose, next.js, schema

I want to save 1 document with multiples subdocuments inside. In this case a Document named 'Scores' and subdocuments that contains 'Player: x, Score: y'. I'm using mongoose with nextjs

**This is my schema:**

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const ScoreSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },

    scores_to_save: [
        {
            player: { type: String },
            score: { type: String }
        }
    ]
});

const Score = models.Score || model( 'Score', ScoreSchema );

export default Score;
```

**This is my API router:**

```
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import Score from "@models/score";

export const POST = async ( req ) => {
    const { userId, scores } = await req.json();
    
    try {
        await connectToDB();

        const newScores = new Score({
            creator: userId
        });

        // Manually data insert for now, just for testing
        newScores.scores_to_save = [
            { player: 'my name', score: '5' },
            { player: 'your name', score: '6' }
          ];

        console.log('TO SAVE Document: ', newScores );

        await newScores.save();

        return new Response( JSON.stringify( newScores ), { status: 201 } );
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response( "Failed to create a new Scores.", { status: 500 } );
    }
}
```

The console.log('TO SAVE Document: ', newScores ); returns:

```
TO SAVE Document:  {
  creator: new ObjectId("652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"),
  _id: new ObjectId("6532cfcd4c76ca7d258d3f0d")
}
```

Totally ignore the 'newScores.scores_to_save' part.

I'm not getting any error at all, but the only thing saved into the database is the 'creator' & '_id' values,

What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is unusual. However, when you do `const newScores = new Score()` an empty array as assigned to `scores_to_save` so there is no need to overwrite it with a new array. If you do `newScores.scores_to_save.push({ player: 'my name', score: '5' }, { player: 'your name', score: '6' })` instead does the same thing happen?

Comment: Hi @jQueeny, thanks to take the time for help!

I just figured out that after any change on the structure of the Model Schema file, we need to restart the local server.

Everything is working fine now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out what was the issue. It looks like after any change on the structure of the Model Schema, we need to restart the local server.

So, I just kill the terminal, open it again and run `npm run dev`.

After that, all start working as expected.

The `console.log('TO SAVE Document: ', newScores );` now returns:

```
TO SAVE B:  {
  creator: new ObjectId("652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"),
  _id: new ObjectId("6533cd6cfbefe01889fd22e7"),
  scores_to_save: [
    {
      player: '652f36c9f6ad40c3aedf0cdf',
      score: '777',
      _id: new ObjectId("6533cd6cfbefe01889fd22e8")
    },
    {
      player: '652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd',
      score: '666',
      _id: new ObjectId("6533cd6cfbefe01889fd22e9")
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that I'm passing real data now as well.

Thanks everyone!